# UISwitch won't let me set default state

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom `UICell` that contains a `UISwitch` element.  When I render my table, `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` will check to see if the users preference matches a specific category, if it does they are subscribed, else they are not.  I have written some logic to toggle the switch based on this result:

```
if let userPreferences = user["preferences"] as? Array<AnyObject>
{
    if userPreferences[indexPath.row].objectId == game.getGameId() {
        prefCell.subscribed?.setOn(false, animated: true)
    }
}
```

I have breakpointed the line where the switch is disabled, and it breaks 9 times out of the current 11 items I retrieve in the `userPreferences` collection, however none of the switches on my UI are updated.  Why is this happening?

**EDIT**: After some further testing it appears that the if statement is always satisfied, this is extremely strange as in the event that the strings don't match, Swift still claims that they did.

For example if I have a list of the ID's

```
xyz12345
abc12345
efg12345
```

And the following loop executed:

```
if let userPreferences = user["preferences"] as? Array<AnyObject>
{
    for preference in userPreferences
    {
       if preference.objectId == game.getGameId()
       {
           prefCell.subscribed.on = true;
       } else {
           prefCell.subscribed.on = false;
       }
    }
}
```

The first comparison could be something like `preference = xyz12345` and `game.getGameId() = abc12345`.  I'd expect the second case to be invoked as these strings certainly do not match, however the case passes as true and the switch is set, why am I witnessing this behaviour?

Comment: You are setting the switch to off (`setOn(false)`) is it your intention?

Comment: yes, by default all switches are enabled, so for clarity I want to disable the switches - however the GUI does not update

Comment: Is `subscribed` non-nil? Break the statement into two lines to check.

Comment: You have to cover all the cases - otherwise your cells will mess up. Try to add else to set your switch on.

Comment: Even adding the else case causes all buttons to be on

Comment: What happens if you change `animated: false`?

Comment: I still get the same result - very strange huh...

Comment: Make sure that it is getting called on the main thread

Comment: I can clarify its on the main thread, this code runs in the background threads completion block on the main thread

Comment: If you made that completionblock and you're sure its on the main thread then prefCell.subscribed must be nil

Comment: I usually just do switch.on = (BOOL) if I want to change a state, but I dont think that has anything to do with your problem.